# Этимология слов "отдых" и "отдохнуть"

Tags: этимология

Откуда произошли слова **отдых** и **отдохнуть**? Мне очень нужна их этимология!

Answer (score 1):

Лексемы **отдохнуть** и **отдых** входят в список 1000 самых употребительных глаголов и имен существительных (частотный словарь русской лексики О. Н. Ляшевской и С. А. Шарова).

По данным "Этимологического словаря современного русского языка", слова появились в русском языке в ХI в. и фиксировались в словарях с XVIII в.

***Отдых*** в русском языке в XI – XII вв. — *отъдъхъ, отъдохъ*; в словарях как **отдых** отмечено с 1731 года.
***Отдыхать*** русском языке в XI-XVII вв. отмечено как *отъдыхати*; **отдыхаю** отмечено в словарях с 1701 года, **отдыхать** с 1771 года.
(Ср. *отдохнуть, дыхание, дышать, отдышаться.*
***Отдохнуть*** – в русском языке отмечено в XI-XVII вв. как *отдъхнγти, поотъдъхнγти*; отмечено в словарях как **отдохнуть** с 1731 года.
Из праславянского языка *отдъхнõти*, однократного глагола на *–нõти*, соотносительного с имперфектом *отдыхати.)

А. А. Зализняк (на основании этимологических словарей славянских языков с
учетом значения приставки **от-** и суффикса **-ну-**) отмечает, что *первоначально* глагол **отдохнуть** имел значение: **перестать задыхаться, восстановить нормальное дыхание**, которое утрачено в современном русском языке (не умереть, остаться живым; успокоиться, убедившись в том, что опасность миновала).
[Этот вывод исследователь сделал, опираясь на статью А. Б. Пеньковского, посвященную анализу глагола **вздохнуть**, и на статью М. Фасмера "дόхнуть, дохнýть, вздох".]

[**Е. А. Курлова, "...отдых"**](http://www.novsu.ru/file/1095219)
Этимологический словарь современного русского языка, А. К. Шапошников